# In windows can I convert a file to linux's UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8

I'm sending a text file in window's UTF-8 to my friend who uses linux.
He wants me to send in linux's UTF-8.
How can I do this easily in winodws?
Can someone recommend some software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between OS regarding UTF-8, there is only one UTF-8.

You may have 2 kinds of problems :

- difference in end of lines (`CR/LF` for windows and `LF` on linux)
- some stupid windows software add a BOM (byte order mask) at beginning of UTF-8 files

Most Windows text editors let you define how files are saved in the settings. Check you don't write the "BOM Unicode" and that you write end of lines as `LF`.